# What is the name of the theory (if there is one) that states lottery winners are more likely to tell others about their lottery entry?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I've previously read about a theory that I remember (correctly or not) being called the "Winning Lottery Theory" which is essentially the following:

> An individual hears about disproportionately more occurrences of other
>   individuals entering a lottery and winning, than they do of others
>   entering a lottery and not winning. This gives the individual a
>   distorted perspective of the odds of actually winning.

The same principle applies to people's testaments of products or services that work for them as opposed to not working for them. The opposite effect also applies, if a detrimental effect occurs. It seems particularly applicable to subjects likely vaccination (eg causing autism), and pseudoscience (eg my back stopped hurting after my homeopathy drops) etc.

**Anyway, the question is this: is there a more standard name for this effect?** Googling "Winning lottery theory" came up with very little. The closest I could find was [this article](http://whybelieve.blogspot.co.nz/2007/11/lottery-winner-theory-of-human-behavior.html) mentioning a "Lottery-Winner Theory", which returns a few more Google results but still not many.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is an example of sample selections, which happens when the dependent variable (winnings) is observed only for a restricted, nonrandom sample (winners). This is also sometimes called [selection bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_bias) or [sampling bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_bias).

Here's [a nice aviation example of SB](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/01/21/selection-bias-and-bombers/) of this problem from John Cook.

In behavioral economics, this sort of cognitive bias is called [availability heuristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Availability_heuristic).